# Vuetify - Observe v-app-bar changes, e.g. onScroll()

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am using the `v-app-bar` component from [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/app-bars/) in my app. I am able to add the `shrink-on-scroll` option, which successfully decreases the `size` prop when scrolled.

My question is: Is there any way to observe changes of the scroll value or height prop of the component, so I can e.g. change a text elsewhere, when the app bar is small.

When I `console.log()` the app bar component, I can see that there are many properties and I've tried adding watchers, however I have had no luck. From what I have read, to usual way to go is to emit values from the child component to the parent. However, as this is a UI-library I cannot add custom emit function.

I am able to retrieve the height value in the `mounted()` function using `console.log(this.$refs.barChild)`, however this is not reactive.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```js
<script>
export default {
    watch: {
        'this.$refs.barChild.height': {
            handler() {
                console.log('changed')
            },
            deep: true,
            immediate: true
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.$watch('$refs.barChild.height', (newValue, oldValue) =>
            console.log(newValue)
        )
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <v-app-bar app fixed color="#F7F7F6" ref="barChild" @onScroll="handleScroll" shrink-on-scroll elevate-on-scroll prominent elevation="3" scroll-target="#main">
  </v-app-bar>
</template>
```

Comment: We will be able to help you better if you provide a CodeSandbox.

Comment: Thank you. I added some code, however my main question is how to do this in general, not necessarily for this specific instance.

Comment: In general you will get a reference to the instance of the AppBar component, and then watch the `computedHeight` property of the AppBar - if the new value is smaller than the old value then the bar has just shrunk, otherwise it has just grew.

Comment: Thank you @IVOGELOV ! That did it. I changed "height" to "computedHeight" in the mounted function and now it works.